# Why for $A^T A$, it is faster to computer the eigenvalues of its inverse than itself?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerics, eigenvalues

I have written the following code in MATLAB. I also observe the same effect in Arnoldi iteration in ARPACK in C.

```matlab
N = 4000;
A = rand(N); % Random entries in Uniform[0,1]
tic
AstarA = A.' * A + 5*eye(N);
toc
AstarAinv = inv(AstarA); % Inverse
tic
eigs(AstarA, 1, "smallestreal") % Eigenvalue with smallest real part
toc
tic
eigs(AstarAinv, 1, "largestreal") 
toc
tic 
svds(A, 1, "smallest");
toc
```

Observations:

1. `eigs(AstarA, 1, "smallestreal")` takes about 16s.
2. `eigs(AstarA, 1, "largestreal")` takes about 8s.
3. `svds(A, 1, "smallest")` takes 6s.

I am perplexed by the result. I do not know what is going on in svds sooooo slow, but for the first two observations, I have implemented Arnoldi iteration in ARPACK in C. I see the same effect - the algorithm converges faster with the inverted matrix.

I could not understand this - if many eigenvalues are very close to zero then surely inverting can help pull clustered eigenvalues apart and speed up convergence. But the smallest eigenvalue of `AstarA` is about 5, which is far from zero. **So why inverting the matrix still helps?**

**The same effect persists when I change** `real` to `abs`. **You cannot say it is because it is easier to work with largest absolute values than smallest values** - "smallestreal" and "largestreal" are fully symmetric concepts.

[Also, although it might not be possible to answer, why is svds faster? Isn't it also using Arnoldi iteration?]